# RegularExpression somente letras na Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Usando a seguinte RegularExpression na Model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$")]
public int ano_da_configuracao { get; set; }
```

Obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei da seguinte forma para aceitar somente letras:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^[A-ZÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/")]
```

achando que podia conseguir o mesmo resultado, porém não funcionou.

Como corrigir esta expressão para que funcione como o primeiro exemplo?

Comment: Já tentou `[RegularExpression(@"^\w+$")]`?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez Não funcionou continua aceitando números. O html esta assim: `data-val-regex="O campo UF deve corresponder à expressão regular '^\w+$'." data-val-regex-pattern="^\w+$" `.

Comment: tentou usar o \D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto seria assim:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use apenas caracteres alfabéticos.")]
public String MinhaString { get; set; }
```

Comment: Era isto mesmo! Mais uma vez obrigado.